# How to access constant with class pointer in python - AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_restframework_2fa.User'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have defined `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_restframework_2fa.User'` in the `settings.py` file of Django application.

`django_restframework_2fa` is the name of the package and it has module named `models` where class `User` is defined.

Now, I want to access that `User()` class using `AUTH_USER_MODEL` constant. How can this be done?

I tried to access it like this `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL(**data)` which should be equivalent to `User(**data)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python module can be imported using `import_module()` method of  `import importlib`. Then to get the attributes of that module use method `getattr()` which takes two arguments `module` and attribute name.

This is how I have accomplished it -

```
def get_class(module_class_string):

    """
    :param module_class_string: full name of the class to create an object of
    :return: class
    """

    module_name, class_name = module_class_string.rsplit(".", 1)

    module_name = module_name + '.models'
    
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)

    return getattr(module, class_name)
```